# Can't set property to object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var data = {};


....

data[someprop][someotherprop] = 'bla bla'
```

I get

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ... of undefined` and `Cannot set property of...`

Yes, the object doesn't have these properties ..yet, but I'm setting them in that line where I get the error lol. So what's up with that?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're trying to set a property inside an object that is itself a property that doesn't exist yet. What happens if you try creating `someprop` on one line **then** setting `someotherprop` in that?

Comment: please show the actual code. Also, setting an property in a property that does not exist yet will not work. You will have to set `someprop` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `someprop` and `someotherprop` are variables, Richard D's answer is correct, if they are hardcoded strings, you could write your code like this:

```
var data = {someprop:{someotherprop: 'value'}};
```

if, however, they are values stored in variables, and you really - really want to cram everything into a single line, try something like this:

```
var data = {window.someprop : {window.someotherprop: 'value'}};
```

where window can be replaced by any object, if the `someprop` value is itself a property of an object:

```
var data = {someForm.name : { formElement.name : formElement.value}};
```

Or jQuery objects, since your tag suggest you're using jQuery:

```
var data= {$('#formId').attr('name'):{$('#formSelect').attr('name'): $('#formSelect').val()}};
```

Note: the jQuery example is not to be recommended, as the id selector is used twice on the same element. jQuery will scan the DOM-tree twice, so you're better of storing your that `#formSelect` element in a variable somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to assign a property to an object that doesn't exist, running that statement is equivalent to

`data.someprop.someotherprop` the parser won't automatically create `data.someprop` for you, hence the error.

You have to initialize `someprop`

```
data.someprop = {};
data['someprop']['someotherprop'] = 'gw ganteng';
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the properties in diffrent steps like this:

```
var data = {};


data[someprop] = {}; 
data[someprop][someotherprop] = 'bla bla';
```

The object data will not have a property named "someprop" before you asssign it.

Comment: You need to put quotes around the property names, otherwise that code still isn't going to work. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXETB/4/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = {};
data[someprop] = {someotherprop:'bla bla'};
```

otherwise `data[someprop]` will be undefined

Comment: var data = { someprop : { someotherprop : 'bla bla' }}; :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `data[someprop]` first:

```
var data = {};
data[someprop] = {};
data[someprop][someotherprop] = 'bla bla'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/zXETB/

Comment: The code in your answer and the code in your jsFiddle aren't equivalent. Taking out the quotes for the property names results in Javascript errors.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I know. I'm assuming `someprop` and `somepotherprop` are set somewhere.